# jquery mmenu.js on single page website

Tags: jquery, mobile, menu, navigation

i've set up this example of my problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/omegaiori/9FdXv/6/): 
see it also in fullscreen because the example is [responsive](http://jsfiddle.net/omegaiori/9FdXv/6/embedded/result/):

what happens is after i click on a menu item when mmenu is activated, the scroll jumps to random anchors, and not to the right one. can anybody help?

i have jquery 1.9.1, mmenu.js and jqueryeasing and these are the inline scripts

```
$(function() {
            $('nav ul li a').bind('click',function(event){
                var $anchor = $(this);
                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
                }, 1000,'easeInOutExpo');
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });



        $(function() {
            $('nav#nav').mmenu({
                configuration: {
                    //  For some odd reason, the header won't stay "fixed"
                    //  when using hardware acceleration
                    hardwareAcceleration: false
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nobody answered but i want to share the fix. Fred, the creator of mmenu, was kind enough to offer some support via email, you can see the fix here: http://jsfiddle.net/9FdXv/8/

here the js:

```
$(function() {
            $('nav ul li a').bind('click',function(event){
                var $anchor = $(this);

                $('nav#nav').one('closed.mmenu', function() {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('html, body').stop().animate({
                            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
                        }, 1000,'easeInOutExpo');
                    }, 10);
                });
                $('nav#nav').trigger('close.mmenu');

                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            });
        });



        $(function() {
            $('nav#nav').mmenu({
                configuration: {
                    //  For some odd reason, the header won't stay "fixed"
                    //  when using hardware acceleration
                    hardwareAcceleration: false
                }
            });
        });
```

hope this helps others

Comment: I've got a similar problem: when I close the mmenu by clicking outside the same mmenu, my page go back to the top instead of remainig on the anchor selected by the menu. Have you got any idea about this?